# GNU/Linux is booting slow

Tags: linux, boot

Lately, my gnu/linux desktop machine is booting slowly. Would you guess what's happening based on the following logs?

This is the output of running

```
$ dmesg -d | cut -d "<" -f2 | sort -nr | head
```

to get the first 10 log events ordered by delta time (-d) option.

```
50,148100>] EXT4-fs (sda5): orphan cleanup on readonly fs
48,447960>] ------------[ cut here ]------------
39,039483>] Adding 1951740k swap on /dev/sda6.  Priority:-1 extents:1 across:1951740k 
10,400851>] wlan0: no IPv6 routers present
5,015258>] init: failsafe main process (759) killed by TERM signal
2,536267>] EXT4-fs (sda5): INFO: recovery required on readonly filesystem
2,076843>] wlan0: authenticate with 64:70:02:a0:5d:28 (try 1)
1,678620>] EXT4-fs (sda7): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
0,907473>] psmouse serio1: synaptics: Touchpad model: 1, fw: 7.4, id: 0x1e0b1, caps: 0xd04773/0xe40000/0xa0400
0,708169>] EXT4-fs (sda5): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro
```

---

This is

```
$ df -ah

S.ficheros       Tamaño Usados  Disp Uso% Montado en
/dev/sda5          9,2G   6,6G  2,2G  76% /
proc                  0      0     0    - /proc
sysfs                 0      0     0    - /sys
none                  0      0     0    - /sys/fs/fuse/connections
none                  0      0     0    - /sys/kernel/debug
none                  0      0     0    - /sys/kernel/security
udev               923M   4,0K  923M   1% /dev
devpts                0      0     0    - /dev/pts
tmpfs              187M   860K  186M   1% /run
none               5,0M   8,0K  5,0M   1% /run/lock
none               934M    22M  912M   3% /run/shm
/dev/sda7          142G   8,8G  126G   7% /home
gvfs-fuse-daemon      0      0     0    - /home/dione/.gvfs
```

and this is

```
$ cat /etc/network/interfaces

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

---

Finally, this is the context of the slowest one.

```
$ dmesg -d | cut -d "<" -f2 | grep -C 18 "orphan cleanup"

0,109007>] Initializing USB Mass Storage driver...
0,000082>] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
0,000002>] USB Mass Storage support registered.
0,047818>] fbcon: inteldrmfb (fb0) is primary device
0,000091>] Console: switching to colour frame buffer device 170x48
0,000025>] fb0: inteldrmfb frame buffer device
0,000002>] drm: registered panic notifier
0,015547>] ACPI Warning: _BQC returned an invalid level (20110623/video-526)
0,000126>] acpi device:01: registered as cooling_device4
0,000192>] input: Video Bus as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/LNXVIDEO:00/input/input4
0,000078>] ACPI: Video Device [GFX0] (multi-head: yes  rom: no  post: no)
0,000053>] [drm] Initialized i915 1.6.0 20080730 for 0000:00:02.0 on minor 0
0,006591>] usb 2-1.5: new high-speed USB device number 3 using ehci_hcd
0,044042>] scsi4 : usb-storage 1-1.5:1.0
0,000137>] usbcore: registered new interface driver ums-realtek
0,190415>] usb 1-1.5: USB disconnect, device number 4
2,536267>] EXT4-fs (sda5): INFO: recovery required on readonly filesystem
0,000004>] EXT4-fs (sda5): write access will be enabled during recovery
50,148100>] EXT4-fs (sda5): orphan cleanup on readonly fs
0,000009>] EXT4-fs (sda5): ext4_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 295219
0,000075>] EXT4-fs (sda5): ext4_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 295218
0,000013>] EXT4-fs (sda5): ext4_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 295204
0,000012>] EXT4-fs (sda5): ext4_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 269196
0,000013>] EXT4-fs (sda5): ext4_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 191299
0,000008>] EXT4-fs (sda5): ext4_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 131978
0,000008>] EXT4-fs (sda5): ext4_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 131499
0,000006>] EXT4-fs (sda5): ext4_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 131498
0,000007>] EXT4-fs (sda5): ext4_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 131492
0,000006>] EXT4-fs (sda5): ext4_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 131458
0,000006>] EXT4-fs (sda5): 10 orphan inodes deleted
0,000002>] EXT4-fs (sda5): recovery complete
0,073855>] EXT4-fs (sda5): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
39,039483>] Adding 1951740k swap on /dev/sda6.  Priority:-1 extents:1 across:1951740k 
0,708169>] EXT4-fs (sda5): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro
0,685423>] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
0,058400>] udevd[420]: starting version 175
0,007700>] lp: driver loaded but no devices found
```

The distribution is Elementary Luna OS, based on Ubuntu from the Debian family.

```
$ uname -a

Linux saturno 3.2.0-67-generic #101-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jul 15 17:46:11 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it's not entirely clear why your drive needs disk checking, it appears to need disk checking when it boots. This can be caused by improperly shutting down your machine, or by a filesystem that's becoming slightly scrambled due to the disk dying. To check if it's the latter, you should install and use the utility smartctl, found in the smartmontools udeb (or smartmontool rpm). The syntax to use the tool is usually "smartctl --all --device=sat /dev/sda" for ubuntu/debian. In the output, find the "Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds" section. If any of the values go up frequently between runs, or have 1000+ errors, you should replace your hard disk.

Comment: If it is the disk, try to reboot the machine a minimum number of times before backing it up.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. It's more probably that it was improperly shut down, but I'll check that. It's always good to know the disk health.